# If $P$ is extraspecial and $xy\ne yx$, then $C_P(\langle x, y\rangle)$ is extraspecial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

A $p$-group $P$ is called *extraspecial* if$P' = Z(P) = \Phi(G)$, hence $P / Z(P)$ is elementary abelian.

> Let $P$ be an extraspecial $p$-group and let $x, y \in P$ be such that $xy \ne yx$. Let $U = \langle x, y \rangle$ and $V = C_P(U)$.
>
> (a) Show that $|P : C_P(x)| = p$.
>
> (b) Show that $|U| = p^3$.
>
> (c) Show that $|P : V| = p^2$.
>
> (d) If $P > U$, show that $Z(V) = Z(P)$ and that $V$ is extraspecial.
>
> (e) Show that $|P : Z(P)| = p^{2e}$ for some integer $e$.

I have solved (a), (b), (c), and (e) using an induction argument utilizing (d). But with (d) I have my problems. As $P' = Z(P) \le C_P(U)$, the subgroup $V = C_P(U)$ must be normal (as $V / P' \le P / P'$ is normal in the abelian group $P / P'$). Further with $Z(V) \unlhd P$ as $Z(V)$ is characteristic in $V$. This gives me $[Z(V), P] \le Z(V)$. Further $Z(P) \le V$ we have $Z(P) \le Z(V)$. But still is it left to show somehow the reverse inclusion $Z(V) \le Z(P)$, or that $|Z(V)| = p$, but I have no idea how to proceed so I am asking for some help?

Comment: $U \cap V = Z(U) = Z(P)$, so $|U \cap V|=p$, and hence $|UV|=|U||V|/|U \cap V|=|P|$,so $UV=P$. Since $Z(V)$ centralizes both $U$ and $V$, we have $Z(V) \le Z(P)$.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Another idea which came to my mind as I am reading your solution. By considering the indices and as $C_P(x) \ne C_P(y)$ we have $P = C_P(x)C_P(y)$, and both are centralized by $Z(V)$, so $Z(V) \le Z(P)$. Would that work too or have I overlooked something?

Comment: I don't know - is it clear that $Z(V)$ centralizes $C_P(x)$?

Comment: @DerekHolt: I guess since $x,y$ generate $U$ we have $C_P(U) = C_P(x) \cap C_P(y)$, and so $Z(V) \le C_P(U) \le C_P(x)$ and similar $Z(V) \le C_P(y)$, right?

Comment: Oh right yes, sorry I was confused about something. That's fine.